# Create multidimensional / nested object in Angular (nested forEach loops)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to understand how to create a multidimensional object or array in Angular / JS. This JSFiddle should explain the problem clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/s3etbdyj/5/

How do I forEach loop within a forEach loop? To summarise:

I have some data which is easy to display in my application.

```
"albums":[{
    "album_id": 1,
    "album_title": "Test Release",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "songs": [{
      "id": 114,
      "title": "Test song",
    }, {
      "id": 115,
      "title": "Test song 2",
    }],
    }, {
    "album_id": 2,
    "album_title": "Blood Sugar Sex Magik",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "songs": [{
      "id": 116,
      "title": "Give It Away",
    }, {
      "id": 117,
      "title": "Under The Bridge",
    }],
 }]
```

As you can see, each "albums" object can have several "songs" objects within it.

I need to loop through this data and rebuild it (so that I can add things and format it as I see fit)

How do I create nested objects data in this structure? Here's what I have so far:

```
$scope.newData = [];

      // create formatted song list
        angular.forEach($scope.origData, function(m) {
                $scope.newData.push({
                  'album_id'  : m.album_id,
                  'album_title'      : m.album_title,
                });
                angular.forEach(m.songs, function(tr) {
                    var obj = {
                        id: tr['id'],
                        title: tr['title'],
                                }
                    $scope.newData.push(obj);
                });
        }, $scope.newData)
```

But that doesn't work. It creates a flat structure:

```
 Object:
  {
    "album_id": 1,
    "album_title": "Test Release",
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
  }
  Object: 
      {
        "id": 114,
        "title": "Test song",
      }
  Object:
      {
        "id": 115,
        "title": "Test song 2",
        }
  etc...
```

Have a look at the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s3etbdyj/5/
Can anyone make my newData look just like my origData, thus explaining how nested objects are created?!
Thanks.

Comment: so. where are you supposed to push the songs? Currently you are pushing them to the same level, where you push the album.

Comment: I want to push them into an object called "songs" within each album. But i can't get the syntax right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $scope.newData = [];

  // create formatted song list
    angular.forEach($scope.origData, function(m) {
            var album = {
              'album_id': m.album_id,
              'album_title': m.album_title,
              'songs': []
            };
            $scope.newData.push(album);
            angular.forEach(m.songs, function(tr) {
                var obj = {
                    id: tr['id'],
                    title: tr['title'],
                };
                album.songs.push(obj);
            });
    }, $scope.newData);
```

Comment: Thats got it! Thanks. That helps me understand what's going on so much better!

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing everything into $scope.newData, of course it's flat. Try creating the album object first, then in your second loop pushing the songs into its songs array.  Something like:

var album = { title : "whatever", songs: [], ...};
angular.forEach(m.songs, function(tr){ album.songs.push({title: "whatever",...})
}
$scope.newData.push(album);

Sorry for the formatting I'll fix it when I'm not on my phone.